# Taoism and other minds

Tags: taoism

Why does wikipedia say that Taoism is solipsism? 1. Does Taoism say that others have no mind's? 2. Does this mean that every Taoist is a person who believes that only He has a mind, and all other people are just philosophical zombies?

Comment: Wikipedia's article on [Taoism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taoism) does not even mention solipsism.

Answer (score 1):

First and most obvious point: Wikipedia! Wikipedia is an excellent resource for simple, factual claims relating to things like maths, history, and the natural sciences. But it's only middling-fair for things in the social sciences, and it can be earnestly abysmal (for various reasons) when it comes to anything political, spiritual, or philosophical.

I don't know which Wikipedia article you're referring to, so I can't check the context (please provide links in the future), but I do know that 'solipsism' is a common misunderstanding of Eastern religions (Daoism, Buddhism, Hinduism, etc) by people steeped in the Western analytical worldview. In the West, 'solipsism' has become a catch-all phrase for any philosophy or worldview that is intentionally introspective, as though self-examination automatically precludes the existence of others. Often the term is used as a loose synonym for 'narcissism' or 'self-involvement', not in the formal philosophical sense as a theory of mind.

I suspect that whoever wrote this *meant* to say that Daoism is a type of [virtue ethic](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/ethics-virtue/), which focuses on the development of virtuous qualities within individuals. That's neither solipsistic nor narcissistic — virtue ethics focus on the individual because improved individuals improve society as a whole — but I doubt most people (and most Wikipedia editors) are overly familiar with the concept.

Comment: Also, transcendentally monistic, is often misunderstood as solipsistic.